# How to join table names to row values to rename columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is what I want to do:

I got the table "t01"

```
+----+-------------+-----+  
| ge | f0          |  f1 |
+----+-------------+------  
|  1 | 10          |  5  |
|  2 | 2           |  4  |
|  3 | 58          |  88 |
|  4 | 66          |  9  |
+----+-------------+-----+
```

Another table  t02:

```
+----+-------------+------+-----+
| ge | f0          |  f1  | f2  |
+----+-------------+------+-----+  
|  1 | 1           |  75  |  10 |
|  2 | 25          |  74  |  55 |
|  3 | 5           |  788 | 66  |
|  4 | 6           |  79  | 11  |
+----+-------------+------+-----+
```

Another table tFE

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| ge | f0     | f1    |  f2  |
+----+-------------+---------+  
|  1 | t01    |  f0   |  Code|
|  2 | t01    |  f1   |  City|
|  3 | t02    |  f0   |Number|
|  4 | t02    |  f1   | Index|
|  5 | t02    |  f2   | CIP  |
+----------------------------+
```

What would I want to do is someting like that :
Table t01:

```
+----+-------------+-----+  
| ge | Code        | City|
+----+-------------+------  
|  1 | 10          |  5  |
|  2 | 2           |  4  |
|  3 | 58          |  88 |
|  4 | 66          |  9  |
+----+-------------+-----+
```

Table t02:

```
 +----+-------------+------+-----+
| ge | Number      |Index | CIP |
+----+-------------+------+-----+  
|  1 | 1           |  75  |  10 |
|  2 | 25          |  74  |  55 |
|  3 | 5           |  788 | 66  |
|  4 | 6           |  79  | 11  |
+----+-------------+------+-----+
```

I got a hundreds of tables like t01, t02 with some that have much more columns, and the names of theirs columns is inside tFE , I want to replace their columns names f0,f1 with their true names inside tFE

Comment: Are you just asking how to rename columns?

Comment: Yes , I want to rename the column name of t01,t02 with their values inside tFE

Comment: Unfortunately in your example the data makes no sense, it lists which table the column names go in, but not the order or anything that relates to the existing column names

Comment: I forgot the list of columns names in tFE, I just edit it

Comment: I'm curious, why you chose a design like that. Why do you store the column names in a table?

Comment: They are not my tables,  the data of t01 t02  came from floppy disk that didn't have much memory

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql Server? Different products....

Comment: Mysql, I remove the tag

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you script that can use to alter columns names in any language that you are comfortable with. I have used PHP to demonstrate this problem.

Fetch all data from table tFE using:

```
SELECT * FROM `tFE`;
```

Iterate over the results from above query.

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $tableName = $result[0]['fo'];
    $oldColumn = $result[0]['f1'];
    $newColum = $result[0]['f2'];
    // Run following query to change the columnName using PDO
    "ALTER TABLE {$tableName} Change  {$oldColumn} {$newColumn} ["Data Type"];"
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I did someting like that in bash